# React Native Project Won't Start due to Error: EISDIR

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

Beginner react native user here.

I tried following [Mosh's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-S5a0eXPoc&t=874s) guide on React Native, but when I run the npm start command, I get this error in the terminal:

```
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
error EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read.

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Error: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\@expo\xdl@57.9.35\src\Project.ts:1917:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-04T16_22_24_340Z-debug.log
```

Here is the verbose log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'web'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'preweb', 'web', 'postweb' ]
5 info lifecycle @~preweb: @
6 info lifecycle @~web: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~web: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~web: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\steve\MyApp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\steve\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @~web: CWD: C:\Users\steve\MyApp
10 silly lifecycle @~web: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start --web' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~web: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~web: Failed to exec web script
13 verbose stack Error: @ web: `expo start --web`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\steve\MyApp
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "web"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ web: `expo start --web`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ web script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

npm version: 6.14.6
node version: 12.18.3
expo version: 3.26.2

Commands I ran:

> npm i -g expo-cli

> expo init MyApp

*selected blank managed workflow

> cd MyApp

> npm start

Any help would be greatly appreciated.